A circular argument in the proof of Proposition 2.3.1 of Bratteli-Robinson
I think the proof of Proposition 2.3.1 of Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics 1 by Bratteli and Robinson, contains a circular argument.
The book uses the following inequality
\begin{equation}
\|\hat{\pi}^{-1}(\hat{\pi}(\hat{A})\| \leq \|\hat{\pi}(\hat{A})\|,
\end{equation}
to prove that $\mathfrak{B}_\pi$ is closed, but the inequality assumes that $\mathfrak{B}_\pi$ is closed.
How can this problem be resolved?

I think that as written, the second part of the proof is wrong, as you say (because completeness is required in the first part of the proof so it cannot be applied to $\hat\pi^{-1}$).
The way I know to go through the proof that $\mathfrak B_\pi$ is closed is the following. As in the book, you get to the point where you have constructed an injective $*$-homomorphism from a C$^*$-algebra onto $\mathfrak B_\pi$.
So the question is how to prove that if $\pi:A\to B$ is an injective $*$-homomorphism and $A,B$ are C$^*$-algebras, then $\pi(A)$ is closed. The proof goes as follows. We know that $\|\pi(a)\|\leq\|a\|$ for all $a\in A$. Suppose that $\|\pi(a)\|<\|a\|$ for some $a\in A$ positive. Choose $f$ continuous and such that $f(\|a\|)=1$, $f|_{[0,\|\pi(a)\|]}=0$. We know that
$$
1=f(\|a\|)\in f(\sigma(a))=\sigma(f(a)), 
$$
so $f(a)\ne0$. But
$$
0=f(\pi(a))=\pi(f(a)).
$$
As $\pi$ is injective this gives us $f(a)=0$, a contradiction. So $\|\pi(a)\|=\|a\|$ for $a\geq0$. For arbitrary $a$,
$$
\|\pi(a)\|^2=\|\pi(a)^*\pi(a)\|=\|\pi(a^*a)\|=\|a^*a\|=\|a\|^2
$$
and thus $\pi$ is isometric. Then $\pi(A)$ is closed.

Thank you for your answer and sorry for the late reply.
I think the first part of the proof, or the proof of the contractiveness of a $\ast$-homomorphism from a unital Banach $\ast$-algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ to a $C^*$-algebra $\mathfrak{B}$ uses the completeness of $\mathfrak{A}$ in order to say that the spectral radius of $A \in \mathfrak{A}$ is $|A|$ or less.
Thus we have to prove that $\mathfrak{B}_\pi$ is complete (in particular, closed) to use the contractiveness of $\hat{\pi}^{-1}$.
What do you think?

No. What I said is that the first part of a proof shows that a $$-homomorphism with domain a $$-algebra and codomain a C$^$-algebra is contractive. When $\mathfrak A$ is a C$^$-algebra, the map $\hat \pi^{-1}$ is $$-homomorphism with domain the $$-algebra $\mathfrak B_\pi$ (with no assumption of closure) and codomain the C$^*$-algebra $\mathfrak A_\pi$ (where one is using the assumption that $\mathfrak A$ is complete). The first part of the proof then implies that $\hat\pi^{-1}$ is contractive, and this is shown to imply it is isometric, and it follows that $\mathfrak B_\pi$ is complete.

How can you prove the first part of the proof without using the assumption that the domain $\mathfrak{A}$ is complete?

That's how the proof is written in the book. Where do you think they use that $\mathfrak A$ is complete?

I think the completeness of $\mathfrak{A}$ is used in $\sup {|\lambda|; \lambda \in \sigma_{\mathfrak{A}}(A)} \leq |A|$.

You are absolutely right. I stand corrected. The hypothesis in 2.3.1 is that $\mathfrak A$ is a Banach $*$-algebra, though, so it is complete. I don't think the argument for the second part can be saved as written. I'll edit the answer to show how I know to prove the result.

Thank you very much!
